# Not able to Receiving simple data from other apps in Oreo Only

Tags: android

```
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

This is not working in Oreo and the same code is working perfectly till android 7.0

Comment: check my answer.

Comment: before you downvote try the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try adding two different intent filters, like:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
    </intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive